Why does Jekyll add unnecessary spacing within <code> tags when converting Markdown to HTML?
I've noticed a peculiar behavior while using Jekyll to convert Markdown files into HTML. Specifically, when I include a code block like this in my Markdown file:
cd blog
Jekyll generates the corresponding HTML as follows:
<div class="highlight">
  <pre class="highlight"><code><span class="nb">cd </span>blog </code></pre>
</div>

The issue arises from the additional space introduced before the text "blog" within the  tag. This extra space seems redundant. Has anyone else encountered this problem, and if so, is there a way to prevent Jekyll from adding this unnecessary spacing within  tags during the Markdown to HTML conversion process? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

The issue seems to be caused by the interaction between the Markdown processor (Kramdown) and the syntax highlighter (likely Rouge).
Try switching to another highlighter.
If nothing else helps, consider manually adjusting the output. I have done a similar thing in a project at work. Tools like sed or awk can strip unwanted spaces.
Sed script example to remove only the space before closing  tags within code blocks:
sed -i 's/ <\/span>/<\/span>/g' _site/**/*.html

